# How to extract space from Ubuntu occupied Partition

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, window

[image: GParted Software]

I want to extract half of the space used by the `sda1` that is being used by my Ubuntu 17 OS to Dual boot with windows.

Is there any safe way of doing this without losing any data?

Comment: This post is for expanding the partition. That is a simple task. My issue is of contracting the Partition @pomsky

Comment: It's about resizing partitions. Did you check this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/166528/? Or this https://askubuntu.com/a/237453/?

Comment: I agree with @pomsky in it is a duplicate.  when in `gparted` you drag right to increase partition size; left to decrease size - so it directly answers your question as it allows for increasing or decreasing size.

Comment: before resizing check out which partition you boot into such as `sda2, sda3..` because removing or adding a partition will change partition order so you may end up with boot failure but it's fixable.

Comment: i have a single partition i.e. sda1

Answer (score 0):

To resize a partition it must not be mounted. As you have only one partition you cannot resize it because your OS is on it.
You can create a live CD/USB with GParted, boot from it and resize the partition -> https://gparted.org/livecd.php
Backup all data on different disk before that!